# While loop Repeats infinitely

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a while loop that populates a dropdown box with values from a mysql table. There are only two matching records and it is repeating them over and over. How do i only display each record once?:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members, sportevents, dates, results, event, userlogin ". 
         "INNER JOIN members AS m ON userlogin.id = m.id " .
         "WHERE userlogin.username = '$un' " . 
         "AND sportevents.id = members.id " . 
         "AND sportevents.event_id = event.id " .
         "AND sportevents.date_id = dates.id " .
         "AND sportevents.result_id = results.id";

echo "<form method='POST' action='display.php'>";
echo "Please Select Your Event<br />";
echo "<select name='event'>";
echo "<option>Select Your Event</option>";
$results = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

    echo "<option>";
    echo $row['eventname'];
    echo "</option>";
                                               }

echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Go'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Are you sure the SQL you're running isn't bringing back duplicates due to the join?

Comment: I agree with Jon Stirling's position; make sure that the SQL Query returns the desired results before suspecting anything is wrong with the loop. Because there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Run the query and test it, loop seems fine.

Comment: try to execute the query with a mysql client (command line or GUI client) to see if the query works. Also check you donn't have more tables with the "eventaname" field, otherwise $row['eventname'];
does not know wich is the correct "eventname to show"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried running that query manually in the mysql monitor? Nothing in your code would produce an infinite loop, so most likely your query is not doing joins as you expect and is doing a cross-product type thing and creating "duplicate" records.

In particular, your query looks very suspect - you're using the lazy "from multiple tables" approach, instead of explicitly specifying join types, and you're using the members table twice (`FROM members ...` and `INNER JOIN members`). You don't specify a relationship between the original members table and the joined/aliased `m` one, so most likely you're doing a `members * members` cross-product fetch.

---

give that you seem to be fetching only an event name for your dropdown list, you can try eliminating the unused tables - ditch `dates` and  `results`. This will simplify things considerable, then (guessing) you can reduce the query to:

```
SELECT event.id, event.eventname
FROM event
INNER JOIN sportevents ON event.id = sportevents.event_id
INNER JOIN members ON sportevents.id = members.id
INNER JOIN userlogins ON members.id = userlogins.id
WHERE userlogins.username = '$un'
```

I don't know if the members/userlogins join is necessary - it seems to just feed sportevents.id through to members, but without knowing your DB's schema, I've tried to recreate your original query as best as possible.

Comment: I know it is complicated. I need to join members-id with loginuser-id. I see the join is causing the repeat. The join ensures that the results is showed ONLY if the id field of the members table is the same as the id field of the userlogin

Comment: How would write the query otherwise while producing the same results?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try changing the `SELECT` statement to a `SELECT DISTINCT` statement.  That'll prevent duplicates of the selected fields.
Either that or reading all the results before displaying them, then de-duping them with something like `array_unique()`.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout My Example. It will be helped for you to understand. Because this code 100% working for me. Study it and get a solution.

And You Should Use `DISTINCT` keyword and `GROUP BY` Keyword. That's the Main Thing to prevent repeating values.

```
    <?php
    $gtid = $_GET['idvc'];
    if(isset($_GET['idvc']))
    {   
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT gallery_types.gt_id, gallery_types_category.gtc_id, gallery_types_category.gt_category, gallery_types_category.gtc_image FROM gallery_types, gallery_types_category WHERE $_GET[idvc]=gtid GROUP BY gt_category");
    mysql_select_db($database,$con);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {?>
            <table>
                <tr>

                    <td width="100px"><?php echo $row['gt_id'] ?></td>
                    <td width="100px"><?php echo $row['gtc_id'] ?></td>
                    <td width="300px"><?php echo $row['gt_category'] ?></td>
                    <td width="150px">
                        <a href='view_all_images.php?idvai=<?php echo $row[gtc_id] ?>' target='_blank'>
                            <img width='50' height='50' src='<?php echo $row[gtc_image] ?>' />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        <?php 
        }   
    }
    ?>
```

Better Understand, Follow Following Method,

`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT  table1.t1id, table2.t2id, table2.t2name FROM table1, table2 WHERE t1id=t2id GROUP BY t2name");`